# Release memory of OpenCV::VideoCapture (or using cvRelease correctly)

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, memory-management

I'm doing [this example](http://www.vislab.usyd.edu.au/moinwiki/OpenCV/OpenCV%20and%20OpenGL). The problem that I have is the memory consumption of the app, it starts around 180 mb going upto 1.5 gb in 30 secs.

```
void VideoCaptureCV::update()
{
    cap >> frame; // cap is cv::VideoCapture

    if(_img == 0)
    {
        _img = new CvMat(frame);
    }

    CvArr *arr = _img;
    CvMat *arrMat, *cvimage, stub;
    arrMat = cvGetMat(arr, &stub);
    cvimage = cvCreateMat(arrMat->rows, arrMat->cols, CV_8UC3);
    cvConvertImage(arrMat, cvimage, 0);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_uid);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, cvimage->cols, cvimage->rows,0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, cvimage->data.ptr);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    w = cvimage->cols;
    h = cvimage->rows;

    // non of the following works correctly, it sends
    // exception: cv::Exception at memory location
    //cvRelease(&arr);
    //cvReleaseMat(&arrMat);
    //cvReleaseMat(&cvimage);
    //cvReleaseMat(&stub);
}
```

Any idea on how to use cvRelease correctly?

Edit 1: Added the error send when using cvRelease

Comment: "non of the following works correctly, it sends"...what?

Comment: Can you really call cvRelease(&arr), if arr is allocated using new? Shouldn't you be calling delete _arr (or _img) ?

Comment: Tried delete arr; same problem, exception: cv::Exception at memory location

Comment: Simple answer: don't mix C with C++ and use the C++ interface for your images, too, and not only for the video capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if(_img == 0)
    {
        _img = new CvMat(frame);
    }

    CvArr *arr = _img;
```

How does this even compile?

You don't need to call `new` with openCV images, they will handle the [memory management](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/memory_management.html) for you, just create the images locally on the stack and let openCV clean up